# java.base not found con javafx:jlink en eclipse

Tags: java, javafx, maven

Tengo un proyecto mvn openjfx en eclipse, he estado usando el plugin por defecto (que viene en el arquetipo que especifica la página de openjfx para instalarlo en eclipse) y corriéndolo sin problemas. Luego modifiqué el POM para crear una imagen jlink pero al intentar correr cambiando los goals a "clean javafx:link" en lugar de "clean javafx:run" aparece un error en el log de la consola de eclipse que comienza con "java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.base not found". No entiendo por qué ocurre esto, supongo que me falta configurar algo relacionado al jdk pero no se que es. El POM es el siguiente:

> ```
> <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
> <groupId>com.materiales</groupId>
> <artifactId>control</artifactId>
> <version>0.0.3-ALPHA</version>
> <properties>
>     <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
>     <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
>     <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
> </properties>
> <dependencies>        <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
>       <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
>       <version>3.12.0</version>
>       <scope>compile</scope>      </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
>         <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
>         <version>18-ea+7</version>
>         <scope>compile</scope>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
>         <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
>         <version>18-ea+7</version>
>         <scope>compile</scope>
>     </dependency>         <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
>       <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
>       <version>5.1.0</version>
>       <scope>compile</scope>      </dependency>       <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
>       <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
>       <version>5.1.0</version>
>       <scope>compile</scope>      </dependency>       <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
>       <artifactId>org.apache.commons.codec</artifactId>
>       <version>1.8</version>
>       <scope>compile</scope>      </dependency>       <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
>       <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
>       <version>2.14.1</version>
>       <scope>compile</scope>      </dependency>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>             <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>3.8.1</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>             <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>3.3.0</version>
>     </dependency>
> </dependencies>
>
> <build>
>
>     <plugins>  
>         <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>             <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>3.8.1</version>
>             <configuration>
>                 <source>16</source>
>                 <target>16</target>
>             </configuration>
>         </plugin>
>         <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
>             <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>0.0.6</version>
>             <configuration>
>                 <jlinkImageName>control</jlinkImageName>
>                 <launcher>launcher</launcher>
>                 <mainClass>com.materiales.control/com.materiales.control.App</mainClass>
>             </configuration>
>         </plugin>
>     </plugins>
>
> </build>
> ```

Y el log que aparece es:

> [INFO] Scanning for projects... [INFO]  [INFO]
> -----------------------< com.materiales:control >----------------------- [INFO] Building control 0.0.3-ALPHA [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]--------------------------------- [INFO]  [INFO] ---
> maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ control --- [INFO]
> Deleting C:\Users\maluna\Documents\eclipse-workspace\control\target
> [INFO]  [INFO] >>> javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.6:jlink (default-cli) >
> process-classes @ control >>> [INFO]  [INFO] ---
> maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ control ---
> [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources. [INFO]
> Copying 2 resources [INFO]  [INFO] ---
> maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ control ---
> [WARNING]
> ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************* [WARNING] * Required filename-based automodules detected:
> [commons-codec-1.15.jar, commons-math3-3.6.1.jar,
> SparseBitSet-1.2.jar]. Please don't publish this project to a public
> artifact repository! * [WARNING]
> ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************* [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module! [INFO] Compiling 8
> source files to
> C:\Users\maluna\Documents\eclipse-workspace\control\target\classes
> [INFO]  [INFO] <<< javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.6:jlink (default-cli) <
> process-classes @ control <<< [INFO]  [INFO]  [INFO] ---
> javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.6:jlink (default-cli) @ control --- [INFO]
> Toolchain in javafx-maven-plugin null [WARNING] Required
> filename-based automodules detected. Please don't publish this project
> to a public artifact repository! Error: Module java.base not found,
> required by com.materiales.control java.lang.module.FindException:
> Module java.base not found, required by com.materiales.control    at
> java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.findFail(Resolver.java:893)   at
> java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.resolve(Resolver.java:192)    at
> java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.resolve(Resolver.java:141)    at
> java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.resolve(Configuration.java:421)
> at
> java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.resolve(Configuration.java:255)
> at
> jdk.jlink/jdk.tools.jlink.internal.Jlink$JlinkConfiguration.resolve(Jlink.java:217)
> at
> jdk.jlink/jdk.tools.jlink.internal.JlinkTask.createImageProvider(JlinkTask.java:536)
> at
> jdk.jlink/jdk.tools.jlink.internal.JlinkTask.createImage(JlinkTask.java:424)
> at
> jdk.jlink/jdk.tools.jlink.internal.JlinkTask.run(JlinkTask.java:276)
> at jdk.jlink/jdk.tools.jlink.internal.Main.run(Main.java:55)    at
> jdk.jlink/jdk.tools.jlink.internal.Main.main(Main.java:33) [ERROR]
> Command execution failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException:
> Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)   at
> org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
> at
> org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
> at
> org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:567)
> at
> org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:434)
> at org.openjfx.JavaFXJLinkMojo.execute(JavaFXJLinkMojo.java:209)    at
> org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)   at
> org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)    at
> org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)  at
> org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)  at
> org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)   at
> org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)     at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)   at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
> at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
> at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
> at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
> org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an
> error: 1 (Exit value: 1)  at
> org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
> at
> org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
> at
> org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:567)
> at
> org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:434)
> at org.openjfx.JavaFXJLinkMojo.execute(JavaFXJLinkMojo.java:209)    at
> org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
> at
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)   at
> org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)    at
> org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)  at
> org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)  at
> org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)   at
> org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)     at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)   at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
> at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
> at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
> at
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
> [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time:  9.402 s [INFO] Finished at:
> 2021-12-07T15:02:42-03:00 [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.6:jlink (default-cli) on project
> control: Error: Command execution failed. Process exited with an
> error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1] [ERROR]  [ERROR] To see the full
> stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR]
> Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. [ERROR]
> [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions,
> please read the following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1]
> http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Answer (score 0):

No pude encontrar la causa exacta de este problema, pero luego me di cuenta de varios problemas asociados con **jlink** y la forma de trabajar del sistema de módulos.

Resulta ser que la gran mayoría de las librerías que estaba usando eran *no modulares*, con lo cual jamás iban a poder crearse imágenes reducidas de la API de java.

Para poder ejecutar **jlink** en un proyecto de este tipo es necesario copiar los archivos en una nueva carpeta, crear una carpeta de nombre `lib` (o el que sea) para todas las librerías, pegar los respectivos `jars` y luego modularizarlos.

En muchos casos esto implica traer aún más bibliotecas y modularizarlas también. Hay mucha info al respecto sobre modularización de archivos `.jar`. Yo lo hice con la ayuda de [esta miniapp](https://github.com/DraqueT/Module-Info-Inject/releases).

Solo se puede usar el comando **jlink** en proyectos totalmente modulares. Si se tiene un proyecto que requiere usar el `classpath` entonces solo se va a poder crear una mini **jre** pero no una imagen de la app completa.

A todos estos pasos los hice manualmente, sin ayuda de ningún **IDE** y ejecutando **jlink** desde la ventana de comandos. Aunque son todos replicables en cualquier **IDE** si no se usa **Maven**.

Answer (score 0):

Me sucedio algo parecido cuando pase a javafx17 asi que te dejo mi solucion. La primeras es el POM y tambien debes configurar la ejecucion para que cargue las librerias.

Necesitas estas dependencias

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
                    <version>17.0.1</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                </dependency>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-graphics -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
                    <version>17.0.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-fxml -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
                    <version>17.0.1</version>
                </dependency>

                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-controls -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
                    <version>17.0.1</version>
                </dependency>

                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-web -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
                    <version>17.0.1</version>
                </dependency>

                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-media -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
                    <version>17.0.1</version>
                </dependency>

                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-base -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
                    <version>17.0.1</version>
                </dependency>

                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-swing -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
                    <version>17.0.1</version>
                </dependency>
```

Luego configurar la ejecucion

```
--module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-17.0.1\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.base,javafx.graphics,javafx.media,javafx.swing,javafx.web,javafx.swt
```

Yo utilizo intellij, y queda en RUN -> Edit Configuration -> Application